# Why my bundle AAB is not signed when using debuggable = true

Tags: android, react-native, expo

I have a working react native build (with expo).

When i add in the build.gradle, to enable debug mode :

```
debuggable true
```

The build is not signed (refused by the app store and i observe the same thing with local jarsigner)

Wihout this line everything work fine, locally and on the store.